# Explosion proneness of my Samsung Galaxy Note 7 device

Tags: samsung, hardware

It's all over the news currently about the Samsung smartphone devices being a fire hazard, exploding, and there being a pertinent recall of such devices which have already caused [property damage](http://bgr.com/2016/09/08/note-7-explode-fire-recall-florida-samsung/) and has also [physically burned people](http://betanews.com/2016/09/11/child-burned-by-exploding-samsung-galaxy-note7-is-his-family-partially-to-blame/) in some cases.

As per [Samsung Will Replace or Refund 1 Million Galaxy Note 7 Phones in the U.S.](http://fortune.com/2016/09/16/samsung-galaxy-note-recall/) post. . .

> Samsung Electronics formally recalled 1 million Galaxy Note 7
>   smartphones sold in the United States, replacing or refunding the
>   flagship phones, whose susceptibility to catching fire.
>
> Earlier this month, Samsung said it would recall all Note 7
>   smartphones equipped with batteries it found to be fire-prone.
>
> <sub>[source](http://fortune.com/2016/09/16/samsung-galaxy-note-recall/)</sub>

### **Questions**

- How do I check if my device is affected by this issue?
- How do I check the eligibility of my device for the recall/defect?
- What else do I need to know or consider?

Answer (score 4):

> ### [Galaxy Note7 Safety Recall](http://www.samsung.com/us/note7recall/?cid=ppc-)
>
> **Samsung Galaxy Note7 Battery Safety Recall and Exchange Program**
>
> Samsung has announced a voluntary recall and exchange program on
>   certain Galaxy Note7 devices in cooperation with the U.S. Consumer
>   Product Safety Commission (CPSC). The affected devices were sold in
>   the U.S. before September 15, 2016. Since the affected devices can
>   overheat and pose a safety risk, if you own a Galaxy Note7, it is
>   extremely important to stop using your device, power it down and
>   immediately exchange it using our U.S. Note7 Exchange Program.
>
> Through the U.S. Note7 Exchange Program, you can:
>
> 1. Exchange your current Galaxy Note7 device with a new Galaxy Note7 as
>      approved by the CPSC available no later than September 21, 2016; or
> 2. Exchange your current Galaxy Note7 for a Galaxy S7 or Galaxy S7 edge
>      and replacement of any Note7 specific accessories with a refund of
>      the price difference between devices; or
> 3. Contact your point of purchase to obtain a refund.
>
> Customers who exchange a Note7 device will also receive a $25 gift
>   card, in-store credit, in-store accessory credit or bill credit from
>   select carrier retail outlets.
>
> Note: The battery cell issue applies only to the Galaxy Note7 sold in
>   the U.S. before September 15, 2016.
>
> **Eligibility**
>
> Please follow the steps below to determine if your Note7 must be
>   replaced through this program. This program only applies to the Note7.
>   You can also use Samsung+ which will automatically check your device.
>
> How do I check my device?
>
> Go to the [Eligibility
>   section](http://www.samsung.com/us/note7recall/?cid=ppc-) and. . .
>
> 1. The IMEI or Serial number will be used to indicate if your device
>      should be exchanged.
> 2. Find your IMEI or Serial number by going to "Apps > Settings > About
>      Phone or General Management > Status > IMEI information or Serial
>      number" or check the back of your phone.
> 3. Enter your IMEI (Serial # for devices without IMEI) number without
>      any spaces below:
>
> and then press the **Check** option there.
>
> **Exchange**
>
> Galaxy Note7 owners can contact the carrier or retail outlet where
>   they purchased their device. If you bought your Note7 from
>   Samsung.com, you should contact us at 1-844-365-6197 and we can help
>   you. If you have any questions or concerns, contact us directly at
>   1-844-365-6197.
>
> - **Carrier/Retailer:** ATT
>
>   - **Website:** [http://www.att.com/esupport/](https://www.att.com/esupport/article.html#!/wireless/KM1122948)
>   - **Contact:** 1-800-331-0500
> - **Carrier/Retailer:** Best Buy
>
>   - **Website:** [http://www.bestbuy.com/site/clp/](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/clp/galaxy-note7-information/pcmcat748302046994.c?id=pcmcat748302046994)
>   - **Contact:** 1-888-237-7289
> - **Carrier/Retailer:** Sprint
>
>   - **Website:** [http://newsroom.sprint.com/news-releases/](http://newsroom.sprint.com/news-releases/sprint-update-on-samsung-galaxy-note-7-exchange.htm?previousArticle=0&nextArticle=12301&gotoArt=%2Fnews-releases%2Fsprint-update-on-samsung-galaxy-note-7-exchange.htm)
>   - **Contact:** 1-888-211-4727
> - **Carrier/Retailer:** T-Mobile
>
>   - **Website:** https://explore.t-mobile.com/samsung-galaxy-note7-recall
>   - **Contact:** 1-844-275-9309
> - **Carrier/Retailer:** U.S. Cellular
>
>   - **Website:** [http://www.uscellular.com/about/](https://www.uscellular.com/about/press-room/2016/samsung-us-cellular-announce-details-product-exchange-program-galaxy-note7.html)
>   - **Contact:** 1-888-944-9400
> - **Carrier/Retailer:** Verizon
>
>   - **Website:** [http://www.verizonwireless.com/smartphones/](https://www.verizonwireless.com/smartphones/samsung-galaxy-note-7/)
>   - **Contact:** 1-800-922-0204
>
> ### Frequently Asked Questions
>
> 1. Is it okay for me to continue using my Note7?
>
>    Your safety is our highest priority. Since affected Note7 batteries
>      can overheat and pose a safety risk, if you own a Galaxy Note7, it is
>      extremely important to stop using your device, power it down
>      immediately and participate in the U.S. Note7 Exchange Program.
>
> ---
>
> 2. What is the problem with the Note7 phone?
>
>    We have identified an issue with certain Note7 battery cells. Your
>      safety is our highest priority. Since affected Note7 batteries can
>      overheat and pose a safety risk, if you own a Galaxy Note7, it is
>      extremely important to stop using your device, power it down
>      immediately and participate in the U.S. Note7 Exchange Program.
>
> ---
>
> 3. If I want to participate in the U.S. Note7 Exchange Program, what do I do?
>
>    To participate in the U.S. Note7 Product Exchange Program, you should
>      contact your carrier or retail outlet. If you purchased your Note7 on
>      Samsung.com, you should contact us directly at 1-844-365-6197.
>
> ---
>
> 4. Are there any other Samsung phones impacted?
>
>    No. This issue is only related to the Note7.
>
> ---
>
> 5. When can I buy a new Note7?
>
>    Our first priority will be to provide exchange program participants
>      with a new Note7 as approved by the CPSC. New Note7s will be available
>      at your carrier and retail outlets no later than September 21, 2016.

<sub>[source](http://www.samsung.com/us/note7recall/?cid=ppc-)</sub>

Comment: Note: all Note 7s now pose a risk to safety, as of October.